# mathematical expression of interaction model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to understand how to write mathematically a mixed effect model.

The model is (I want to check the growth rate of rats in a different countries across the variable day adding the interaction of the 2 factor level Country to the growth rate):

```
lmer(Volume ~ Country * Day + (1 | Rat.ID))
```

In R I extracted the equation by using the function extract_eq() for broom.mixed package, obtaining:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{lVolume}_{i}  &\sim N \left(\alpha_{j[i]} + \beta_{1}(\operatorname{Day}), \sigma^2 \right) \\
    \alpha_{j}  &\sim N \left(\gamma_{0}^{\alpha} + \gamma_{1}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Country}_{\operatorname{England}}) + \gamma_{2}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Day} \times \operatorname{Country}_{\operatorname{England}}), \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}} \right)
    \text{, for Rat.ID j = 1,} \dots \text{,J}
\end{aligned}
$$

But I don't think it is correct since it's a bit confusing the $i$ and $j$ and the interaction coefficient and the meaning of the $\gamma$ variable.

So my first attempt was I considering the effect cofficents and the interaction term :

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta_1*Day + \beta_2*Day*Country$$

**Update**

I tried to understand the model again, and arrived to this:

$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_{0CountryA} + 1I_{Country_i = CountryA}+
\beta_{1CountryA} \times Day_{ij} \times 1I_{Country_i = CountryA}+
\beta_{1CountryB} \times Day_{ij} \times 1I_{Country_i = CountryB}+
\eta_{i0} +e_{ij}$$

where every rat i and day j with observations y (Volume).
Is this correct?

But still, here I don't have a representation of the model in terms of expected values and variances.

Could I have some help/hints to understand this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion in interpreting the coefficients reported by the `extract_eq()` function of the [`equatiomatic` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=equatiomatic) probably comes from the need of the package to handle a large number of model structures. The symbols reported by the `extract_eq()` function can be seem unnecessarily complicated in this simple case, but the function needs to handle a wide variety of models.

The main trick here is to recognize that only the rats, represented by $j$ in the `extract_eq()` output, have random effects in your case. Any term that omits $j$ is fundamentally part of the fixed-effect model, even if `extract_eq()` happens to represent it as part of a random effect. Any term independent of $j$ in the mean value presented by `extract_eq()` as part of a random effect can be moved out of the random effect and into the fixed-effect part of the model.

Let's start with your own "first attempt" model but write out all the terms and adjust the symbols of some coefficients to show how they correspond to the output from `extract_eq()`:

$$ Y_i = (\gamma_0^{\alpha} +\alpha_{i}) + \beta_1 D_i + \gamma_1^{\alpha} C_i + \gamma_2^{\alpha} D_i C_i + \epsilon_i$$

where $i$ is an index for the individual observations , $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$ is an overall intercept, $\alpha_{i}$ is the extra intercept to be modeled as a random effect (depending on which rat $j$ is being observed in observation $i$, or $j[i]$), $D$ represents Day, $C$ is Country (0 for the reference country and 1 for the other choice, England), and $\epsilon$ is random error. The $\epsilon$ values are assumed to be distributed normally with the variance $\sigma^2$ reported in the first term by `extract_eq()`.

For now, ignore the superscript $\alpha$ on some of the coefficients. That's just for identification of where the coefficients come from (explained below).

In your mixed-effects model, the random effects will all be incorporated into $\alpha_i$. The value for observation $i$ depends on the rat $j$ being observed; `extract_eq()` represents that as $\alpha_{j[i]}$.

The mean value in the first term reported by `extract_eq()`

$$N \left(\alpha_{j[i]} + \beta_{1}(\operatorname{Day}), \sigma^2 \right) $$

includes a term, $\beta_{1}(\operatorname{Day})$, that is independent of the (rat) random effect indexed by $j$ and can thus be removed into the fixed-effect part of the model, as I did above to give the $\beta_1 D_i$ term. Furthermore, in your case, $\sigma^2$ is independent of $j$ and thus is part of the model for the fixed effects.

Although the coefficients in the output from `extract_eq()` look complicated, that's because they include information about which higher-level coefficients are being modeled (allowing the function to handle more complicated models). For example, the $\alpha$ superscript in the $\gamma_1^{\alpha}$ coefficient for `Country` just means that this $\gamma$ coefficient is part of the model for the overall model intercept $\alpha$; similar interpretation holds for the superscript $\alpha$ in $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$ and $\gamma_2^{\alpha}$.

In your particular case, the $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$, $\gamma_1^{\alpha}$ and $\gamma_2^{\alpha}$ coefficients are constants independent of rat $j$, so you can remove their associated terms from the mean value $$\gamma_{0}^{\alpha} + \gamma_{1}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Country}_{\operatorname{England}}) + \gamma_{2}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Day} \times \operatorname{Country}_{\operatorname{England}})$$ reported by `extract_eq()` for $\alpha_{j}$ and put them into the fixed-effect part of the model. I did that above to provide the $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$, $\gamma_1^{\alpha} C_i$ and $\gamma_2 D_iC_i$ terms in my proposed model.

That leaves only the following for modeling the random effect $\alpha_{j}$:

$$\alpha_j \sim N(0,\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2).$$

That's just a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2$. So in the model for $Y_i$ that I proposed initially, the only random effect is $\alpha_{i}$. For the rat $j$ evaluated in observation $i$ ($j[i]$), that has the specific value $\alpha_{j[i]}$.

So in the model I initially wrote, the fixed effects are: $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$ for the expected value when $D=0$ (`Day` of 0) and $C=0$ (the reference `Country`); $\beta_1$ is the extra change per `Day` when $C=0$; $\gamma_1^{\alpha}$ is the extra contribution of `Country` England over the reference `Country` at `Day= 0`; $\gamma_2^{\alpha}$ is the extra contribution of $D$ and $C$ when `Day` isn't 0 and `Country` is England. The random intercept effects $\alpha_j$ specific to individual rats $j$ have a variance $\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2$. Those random effects are thus for hypothetical differences about the overall intercept $\gamma_0^{\alpha}$ among rats at `Day` 0 in the reference `Country`. Finally, there is additional variance $\sigma^2$ about all of those individual contributions to the model.

Comment: I thought that the $\beta_{1}$ was the slope for the first Country and then it would be a $\beta_{2}$ for the other Country, is this correct? Also, you said that the coefficients $\gamma_{0}$ is the overall and the $\gamma_{1}$ is for the first level of Country and $\gamma_{2}$ for the other one, can these ones be interpreted as $\beta_{2}$ and $\beta_{3}$?  This is related more on the update that I did if makes sense of course.

Comment: @RosaMaria no, that's not the way that `extract_eq()` represents its coefficients or how coefficients are typically modeled. That function needs to have more complicated terminology to handle different types of models. You can call the coefficients anything you want so long as they are consistent with the model and they make sense. `Country A` (the reference, Chile I recall for your data) is assumed to be the case for the intercept and for the baseline values of all non-interaction terms.

Comment: In the `extract_eq()` terminology $\beta_1$ is thus the slope per `Day` in Chile, as you understand. $\gamma_1$ is the _difference_ between England and Chile when `Day` is 0. $\gamma_2$ is the _extra difference_ when `Country` is England and `Day` is not 0. These meanings of fixed-effect coefficients and interaction terms aren't any different from what you have in standard fixed-effect models. The random effects just add extra terms to the fixed effects.

Comment: Ohh ok. And regarding the $\alpha_j \sim N(0,\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2).$ this term came from the extract(), but then in the model you proposed is it ok to assume $\epsilon_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ for the fixed effects? and for the random effect it would be $\gamma_j \sim N(0,\sigma_{\alpha_j}^2).$ ?

Comment: @RosaMaria yes, except that there seems to be a typo in your last expression: it should be $\alpha_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\alpha_j})$. I've always found it easiest to pull out all of the fixed-effect terms first so that random effects and residual errors have 0 means. That works well for simple models, but `extract_eq()` needs to be able to handle models of fairly arbitrary complexity.

Comment: Ok, thanks, These models are quite complicated ones you want to understand it with examples hehe or maybe I am just bad hehe Last question, in this model lmer(Volume ~ Country * Day + (1 | Rat.ID)) does it make sense to think that the marginal distribution of each Country is just subseting the predicted values of each country and their respective confident intervals, then we would have 2 curves that represent each country as the estimated growth rate, right ?

Comment: @RosaMaria marginal distributions aren't best based on subsets. It's best to estimate them from the model so you use all of the available information. You can get an idea of what's going on, and reliable marginal estimates, for example from the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans). There's also information under the [`lsmeans` tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lsmeans?tab=Votes) on this site.